# Google Game Services GamesClient constructor undefined, Android

Tags: android, service, constructor

I have been having trouble setting up the GamesClient object for my Google Play Game Services.

So I have my main activity, which extends BaseGameUtilities. 
In the onCreate() method I try to set up my GamesClient

```
GamesClient.Builder gameClientBuilder = new GamesClient.Builder(getBaseContext(), this, this);
```

In Eclipse I get the error: "The constructor GamesClient.Builder(Context, MainActivity, MainActivity) is undefined"

I have also tried the following calls with no success:

```
 GamesClient.Builder gameClientBuilder = new GamesClient.Builder(this, this, this);
```

and

```
GamesClient gameClient = new GamesClient.Builder(getBaseContext(), this, this).create();
```

and

```
GamesClient gameClient = new GamesClient(getBaseContext(), this, this).create();
```

I'm not sure if this is due to where I am calling this, or to do with how I am calling this. Any help much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do like this GamesClient `GamesClient gc = (new GamesClient.Builder(getBaseContext(), this, this)).create();` assuming you've implemented the needed methods for callbacks.